# Capture 3DModel in high quality

Tags: wpf, 3d

I'm trying to capture my WPF Viewport3D, the problem is that no matter what I do it doesn't captured in high quality, what should be the parameters for the RenderTargetBitmap for best qualiity ?

```
 RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                          (int)viewport3D.ActualWidth, (int)viewport3D.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(viewport3D);
PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (Stream stm = File.Create(m_captureWithoutMainModelFileName))
{
   png.Save(stm);
}
```

I've tried to save the image as BMP as well but it didn't improve the quality.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is with Dpi set to 96,96. On high resolution screen this is no longer the case on Vista/Seven.

```
PresSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual( TheViewPort3D );
dpiX = 96 * PresSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;  
dpiY = 96 * PresSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and the result is a white image with nothing in it.

Comment: ooops. forgot to multiply by 96 :-/  Check the values with debbuger.

Comment: Now there is an image, but the quality is just the same as in the begining

Comment: is it the same quality as the screen ? because one way of doing what you want to achieve would be to perform a render in a bigger control. Could you describe the quality issue ? (resolution, color, compression, ...)